# Is it good to use Spring AsyncTaskExecutor to update DB?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am trying to make an AJAX call from the UI. This should just start a asynchronous process to update the DB based on few conditions. Is it good to use:

1. Spring AsyncTaskExecutor
2. FutureTask
3. Trigger

Or is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: What Java server are you on? Also, how long do you expect the process to run?

Comment: The question should be modified and IMHO reopened because it is a good question of *What are some implementation choices for updating a database with out blocking the UI given X*.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall On Tomcat and the process takes less than a minute.

Comment: @Daemonthread yes but 5000 users doing something like that all at once at best you'll have 5000 objects in an in memory queue... worse case you have 5000 threads trying to run at the same time. In my own web app dev experience (IMHO)... if it takes more than a couple of seconds I push it to an external queue.

Comment: @AdamGent Do you have any link to set up RabbitMQ? Does it run as a separate instance (just to check price on AWS)?

Comment: @Daemonthread there is a package for almost every major Linux distribution. Just google your "os" + "rabbitmq".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your requirements its hard to tell but...:

If you plan on scaling I would use either:

- A persistent transactional queue like **RabbitMQ** or **Redis** if the data is important (ie you don't want to drop an action) and you want to support other languages like Python.
- OR **Akka** if you don't care about dropping actions/messages.

The problem with TaskExecutor aka Java ExecutorService is that its essentially an in memory JVM queue that is mutable (your callable/runnables passed to it can have state and can be mutable). Or better way to put it is the messages in the queue run themselves.

With an ExecutorService if your server goes down and a message is in the queue you can say bye bye to the message. And of the course the message can not be shared with other processes.

**Akka** and **RabbitMQ** instead of an ExecutorService on the other hand provides a better abstraction and will make it easier to scale because it is essentially "event" based. The behavior of the message is separated from the data.

With out knowing your DB I can only take a guess that a "trigger" would be a bad idea.

**I think this is an important question because if you do this wrong all over the place (combining behavior and state for async) it can be very difficult to make the switch.**

Comment: Why? Queues scale way better than a simple java executor service.

Comment: queue is not the question though. question is writing to database asynchronously. user might not have the luxury or infra to be able to use a queue at the moment. they are indeed great but given circumstances is this feasible hence they require some amount of work as well.